# My site's robots.txt was blocking everyone for a year. What to do now that I fixed that?

Tags: seo, google, robots.txt

My site's robots.txt was blocking everyone for a year (The "Discourage search engines from indexing this site" option was checked in WordPress).

I guess Google will re-try to crawl it in the upcoming days (there is at least one site linking to it right now)? Or should I re-submit the site to Google?
Here is what I had (and just removed today) in my `robots.txt`:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oooooooooooooooops! It'll just take time ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google will fetch your updated robots.txt within the next few days and update their crawlers accordingly. Keep in mind this doesn't mean they will start crawling your site immediately and doesn't mean your pages will be indexed soon or rank well. It just means will know your pages are available for crawling but that is the first step to getting your pages into their index.

Comment: ...and submit a sitemap in GWT.

Comment: Start adding new fresh content and update your site as often as possible with new content. Show google you're making updates often. The more frequent the better, try and get some good natural links back to your site and that should all help along with the above.